# Kill hanging function in Python in multithreaded enviorment

Tags: python, multithreading, cython, cpython

I would like to kill a function that executes to long. What is important this function is *inside C extension (wrapped in Cython)*, and I would like this solution to work in multithreaded enviorment. Since it is wrapped in Cython this thread could hold GIL.

I have no control whatsoever on what is happening inside this extension (and I think that this code will not respond to interrupts).

I'm fairly certain that this code will be only run on Unix machines. But question [Python kill hanging function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468904/python-kill-hanging-function) does not apply because I think that signals would not work in multithreaded enviorment (AFAIK it is undefined which thread will catch them) --- but I might be wrong on this one :) so correct me.

Is there any way for me to resolve this without spawning new processes.

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/323993/99057). In general: no, there is no safe way to do that.

Comment: I suspected that this might be a hard problem.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550418/how-to-interrupt-native-extension-code-without-killing-the-interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to wrap this function in another python process and if needed kill that process.

A piece of advice for anyone who googles this question: since process startup time (starting interpreter, loading modules and then loading data into memory) can last couple of seconds you need to group your function calls so this overhead won;t kill you (so there is no reusable solution really).

Example solution, was posted to na another question: [How to interrupt native extension code without killing the interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550418/how-to-interrupt-native-extension-code-without-killing-the-interpreter).