# Is there distributed task queue in Python that enables me to kill hanging tasks that are not willing to cooperate

Tags: python, multithreading, celery, task-queue

Basically I have a lot of tasks (in batches of about 1000) and execution times of these tasks can vary widely (from less than second to 10 minutes). I know that if a task is executing more than a minute i can kill it. These tasks are steps in optimization of some data mining model (but are independent of each other) and are spending most of the time inside some C extension function so they would not cooperate if I tried to kill them gracefully.

Is there a distributed task queue that fits into that schema --- AFAIK: celery allows aborting tasks that are willing to cooperate. But I might be wrong.

I recently asked similar question about killing hanging functions in pure python [Kill hanging function in Python in multithreaded enviorment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881191/kill-hanging-function-in-python-in-multithreaded-enviorment).

I guess I could subclass celery task so it spawns a new process and then executes its payload aborting it's execution if it takes to long, but then I would be killed by overhead of initialization of new interpreter.

Comment: Did you take a look at ``IPython.parallel``?  It supports load balancing and timeouts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) supports [time limiting](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/workers.html#time-limits). You can use time limits to kill long running tasks. Beside killing tasks you can use *soft* limits which enable to handle *SoftTimeLimitExceeded* exceptions in tasks and terminate tasks cleanly.

```
from celery.task import task
from celery.exceptions import SoftTimeLimitExceeded

@task
def mytask():
    try:
        do_work()
    except SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
        clean_up_in_a_hurry()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pistil](https://github.com/meebo/pistil/) allows multiple process management, including killing uncooperative tasks.

But:

- it's beta software, even if it powers gunicorn which is reliable
- I don't know how it handle 1000 processes
- Communication between process is not included yet, so you'll have to setup your own using for example [zeromq](http://zeromq.github.com/pyzmq/)

Another possibility is to use the [timer signal](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html?highlight=signal#signal.alarm) so it raises an exception in 36000 seconds. But signals are not trigered if somebody acquire the GIL, which you C program might do.

Answer (score 0):

When you revoke a celery task, you can provide it with an optional `terminate=True` keyword.

```
task.revoke(terminate=True)
```

It doesn't exactly fit your requirements since it's not done by the process itself, but you should be able to either extend the task class to be able to commit suicide, or have a reccurring cleanup task or process killing off tasks that have not completed on time.